# Creating article pagination

Tags: silverstripe

Hi I'm using silverstripe 2.4.7 and I'm having difficulty getting the pagination to work. I've created a function in my page.php to get the latest articles like so

```
function AllNewsPosts($num=1) { 
$news = DataObject::get_one("NewsHolder"); 
return ($news) ? DataObject::get("NewsEntry", "ParentID > 0", "Date DESC", "", $num) : false; 
}
```

Then when i put this function into the control and pagination tags one article shows up however the links to the concurrent articles do not work - essentially the pagination is not working and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
<% if AllNewsPosts %>
        <% control AllNewsPosts %>
          <div class="event">
           <h2>$MenuTitle |<span class="date"> $Date.Time $Date.Long</span></h2>
           <p>$Content.FirstParagraph</p>
            <a href="$Link">See more about this event</a>
          </div>
        <% end_control %> 
        <% else %>
        <div class="no-entry">'There are no entries'</div>
        <% end_if %>

        <% if AllNewsPosts.MoreThanOnePage %>
  <div id="PageNumbers">
    <p>
      <% if AllNewsPosts.NotFirstPage %>
        <a class="prev" href="$AllNewsPosts.PrevLink" title="View the previous page"><span class="yellow-background">Prev</span></a>
      <% end_if %>

      <span>
          <% control AllNewsPosts.PaginationSummary(0) %>
          <% if CurrentBool %>
            <span class="current">$PageNum</span>
          <% else %>
            <% if Link %>
              <a href="$Link" class="numbers" title="View page number $PageNum">$PageNum</a>
            <% else %>
              &hellip;
            <% end_if %>
          <% end_if %>
        <% end_control %>
      </span>

      <% if AllNewsPosts.NotLastPage %>
        <a class="next" href="$AllNewsPosts.NextLink" title="View the next page"><span class="yellow-background">Next</span></a>
      <% end_if %>
    </p>
  </div>
<% end_if %>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following answer is for Silverstripe 2.4. This should not be used for Silverstripe 3.0+ sites. From 3.0 and onwards the [PaginatedList](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-PaginatedList.html) object makes [pagination much easier](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/pagination).

You are not setting a limit on how many entries to retrieve in your query, or where to start from.

The following tutorial explains how to apply pagination to a set of data objects exactly as you are trying to do:
http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/paginating-a-filtered-dataobjectset/

Here is an attempt at altering your function to include limit and start as needed for pagination:

**PHP**

```
function AllNewsPosts() {
    if(!isset($_GET['start']) || !is_numeric($_GET['start']) || (int)$_GET['start'] < 1) 
    {
        $_GET['start'] = 0;
    }

    $SQL_start = (int)$_GET['start'];

    $newsEntries = DataObject::get('NewsEntry', '', 'Date DESC');
    $doSet = new DataObjectSet();
    foreach ($newsEntries as $newsEntry) {
        if ($newsEntry->canView()) {
            $doSet->push($newsEntry);
        }
    }
    $doSet->setPageLimits($SQL_start, 10, $doSet->Count());
    return $doSet;
}
```

Note the above will display 10 items per page. You can change this to however you need per page.

Comment: This approach seems to be deprecated now, in favor of: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/howto/pagination

Comment: @Kzqai - Yes this answer is for Silverstripe 2.4. This should not be used for any Silverstripe 3.0+ sites. I will put a version note in the answer to make this clear.